# Javascript Statement Order of Execution

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
var confirm = confirm('Are you sure?');
```

I've just tested this statement, and I was given an error stating that `confirm` is not a function.

I detected immediately that the variable name was overwriting it.  However my question is why?

I know that functions are first class, and that declaring a variable of the same name as function will overwrite it within the relative scope.  But my confusion comes from what I thought was an order of execution from "right to left", I.E. the function call is made before the destination is determined.

Does the variable become defined in this case before the function call?

Comment: _"Does the variable become defined in this case before the function call?"_ - Yes. Within the given scope all of the variables are defined before the code in that scope is executed, and they are initially given the value `undefined`. Read up on JS variable "hoisting".

Comment: looks fine here http://jsfiddle.net/batug0o5/1/

Comment: `var` is not an executable statement, subject to rules of top-to-bottom or right-to-left or any other execution order. It's a **declaration** which, as @nnnnn says, is hoisted.

Comment: @Naeem-Shaikh - That's different because in your fiddle you have both a function declaration and a variable with the name `confirm`. The OP (presumably) was expecting the function call to be `window.confirm()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've just read the article on hoisting and it makes sense now, however, the example by @Naeem-Shaikh is strange, because looking at it I would have thought the same thing would have happened.  `var confirm` to overwrite `function confirm()`.

Comment: The function declaration is kind of like a variable declaration. So once `confirm` has been declared by `function confirm() {}` the `var confirm` doesn't redeclare it. Similarly if you have `var confirm` more than once the second and subsequent ones don't redeclare it. (Note also that if all you want to do is prompt the user you don't need the variable at all, just `if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { /* do something */ }`).

Comment: Cheers @nnnnnn thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to JavaScript's variable hoisting:

```
function myFunction() {
    // ...
    var confirm = confirm('Are you sure?');
    // ...
}
```

becomes :

```
function myFunction() {
    var confirm;
    // ...
    confirm = confirm('Are you sure?');
    // ...
}
```

You will need to do the following to enforce your meaning:

```
function myFunction() {
    // ...
    var confirm = window.confirm('Are you sure?');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In any case, overriding the `confirm()` function like that is not a very good idea. You should probably have `var confirmResult = window.confirm('Are you sure?');` to keep it clean

Comment: @deitch It was a slip on my part, I've since renamed the variable.  I just wanted to know what was causing this behavior :)

Comment: Got it. I think @Phylogenesis did a good job explaining it with variable hoisting.